# SQLite, can't delete columns

Tags: android, sqlite

**UPDATE: See self-answer, "fixed, need to channge the where clauses"**

I have set a content provider, for some reason I am able to to delete a row this way:

```
getContentResolver().delete(myUri, "_id=" + "3", null);
```

but i am not able to delete a row that way:

```
getContentResolver().delete(myUri, "NAME=" + "chris", null);
```

---

getting this error:

`02-15 15:48:08.197: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3043): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: chris: , while compiling: DELETE FROM User WHERE NAME=chris`

---

I have checked my database file, and it is there.. but for some reason i can delete columns from my database only by the _id column,

how can i fix this?

error:

`02-15 15:48:08.197: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3043): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: idanmoshik1: , while compiling: DELETE FROM User WHERE USER_NAME=idanmoshik1`

*`User` is the name of my table.

thanks,

Moshik

Answer (score 3):

You should add single quotes (') around `chris` and `idanmoshik1` like this

```
getContentResolver().delete(myUri, "NAME='chris'", null);
```

Comment: Could you explain why? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Much better, forget about escaping quotes and other subtleties using

```
final int n = getContentResolver().delete(myUri, "NAME = ?", new String[] {"user's name"});
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed, need to channge the where clauses

Comment: Why don't you correctly close your question or tag answer 1 or 2 as the correct answers?